# Computed column width is different than css declared width for column. How does browser decide width?

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser, internet-explorer-7

Let's say I have an html table with a css declared width of 750px. It has 5 columns and each column has a width of 50px, declared using css (all td's have a 50px width). Obviously, the sum of the columns' widths is 250px which is less than 750px.

When the browser renders the table, each column has a different computed width. I have one column which has 5 spaces only but a computed width of over 100px ( a lot more than 5  's).

All columns fit their included text plus some extra blank spaces. No hard coded column widths are in the markup. Just a single 50px in the css for the 'td'.

How does the browser compute the rendered width of each column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set the width of table columns, it's just a recommended minimum width, that the browser tries to honor if possible. The actual width of the columns are calculated from the size of their content, dividing the leftover space evenly between the columns.

If any of the columns would end up narrower than the width that you specified, the browser would try to adjust it if there is free space in other columns, but in your case the columns are already over the minimum.

The actual algorithm to calculate the cell sizes differs from browser to browser, which means that the columns will end up slightly different depending on what browser you use.

Comment: The longest content in each column is less than the computed width. Every column has extra spaces. No column is narrower than my width. Does the browser try to throw extra spaces in each column *equally* to get to the table width? The keyword is equally here. I have a column which has only hard coded spaces, no text, but it ends up having a wider column than the sum of the spaces.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich: Yes, the extra space is divided equally, or proportionally, across the columns, according to some unknown algorithm in the browser.

Answer (score 17):

You need to use the `table-layout` style. There's 3 possible values:

- `auto`. The default. Width is dependent on content.
- `fixed`. Depends on the stated widths in the CSS.
- `inherit`. Inherits the value from it's parent.

In your case you need to use `table-layout: fixed` on your table element.

Comment: Lo these many years, still a very helpful answer

Answer (score 2):

Browsers attempt to fit the cells within the table width, expanding/contracting the `td`s as needed.

So, you set the table at 750px, but only gave 250px of width. In that case, the browser will resort to its traditional spacing scheme where, based on the content in each cell, attempts to evenly space out the cells.

You can read more about how this works [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#notes-tables).

Answer (score 0):

This is called the box-model. padding and borders are added to the elements width. So a DIV element with `padding: 10px; width: 50px; border: 1px solid black;` is actually 72 pixels in width. I expect your td's have a border or padding?

Comment: Border collapse also comes into play when dealing with tables.

Comment: No border. No padding. No spacing.