# Table td width 2px more than designated

Tags: html, css, less

I have a table with the following CSS:

```
width: 100%;
border-spacing: 0px;
table-layout: fixed;
```

I then have 3 columns specified with the following classes:

```
@UsedColumnWidth: 26px;
@DeleteColumnWidth: 18px;

.UsedCountColumn {
    width: @UsedColumnWidth;
}
.DeleteColumn {
    width: @DeleteColumnWidth;
}
.CapabilityColumn {
    /*width: @ContainerWidth - @UsedColumnWidth - @DeleteColumnWidth;*/
    /*width: 100px;*/
}
```

I noticed when looking in chrome developer tools that the width's of my `UsedCountColumn` and `DeleteColumn` is 2 more pixels than I have specified and I cannot figure out why this occurring. I thought that maybe border-spacing was messing it up, but I have that set to 0. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: A wild guess.  Did you reset your css margins and paddings?  Else maybe if you can set up a testing environment like jsfiddle or such, me or some other can take a look at it :)

Comment: @j08691 It's used to declare variables in LESS CSS

Comment: @Daniel You were right. It was the padding. When I looked in the computed styles, I did not see a padding value set so I thought that wasn't a problem. I would like to know why it is adding padding without it showing in the computed style.

Comment: @Justin: This related question might help you understand your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671689/computed-column-width-is-different-than-css-declared-width-for-column-how-does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why its adding the padding without showing it.  I take it that you´re using LESS :)

If we are  talking about the "browser default css" then there are some padding and margin for sure.

The reason people are making reset.css documents is because browers have different "default css values".

Eg. some browsers have a more gray/yellow´ish background, where others are totally white.

In order to ensure a better layout and that it look the same in other browsers, you would need to do a css reset.

example.

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   /* ect styles */
}
```

And ofc..

total visual width = padding + width + border

total fill width  = padding + margin + width + border

same goes for height ofc :)

Comment: I hope my answer was helpful aswell as my comment was ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is because you have a 1px border, adding a total of 2px to the element. If this is the case, you can still keep the border, but should either add [`box-sizing`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/moz-box-sizing) or use [`outline`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/outline) instead.