# Computed width is different from the real width of a td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I am doing some manipulations on `td` tags using jQuery - I'm setting their width to be the same as the width of a `td` in another table (actually this is a fixed-header-table plugin, so I have to tables - one for the header and one for the main content. The corresponding `th`s and `td`s should have the same width).

### The problem

All calculatinos work fine if I look at 'Computed style' in Chrome - the widths are set properly.
However, the *real* width is different than the 'computed width'!

See this picture of the computed style of the `td` element:
[image: td-computed-style]
Now you may think that the actual width of the element will be <kbd>1+1+96+1+1 = 100</kbd>, but it is 99!
[image]

I found this question - [Computed column width is different than css declared width for column. How does browser decide width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671689/computed-column-width-is-different-than-css-declared-width-for-column-how-does) and following the advice I used `table-layout: fixed;`. I used `border-collapse: collapse;`, either, in order to remove the space between the columns, so I don't expect this will be the problem.

### The code

Here is a part of my code which sets the td `width`s:

```
$('thead th, tbody tr:first td').each(function(i, el){

    i %= col_count; // I'm using because we go through 2 lines.
                    // It shows at which td we are. */

    // col_width is an array with already calculated
    // widths (using .outerWidth()) for each column */

    // if the needed width is the same as the current td's,
    // we can go to the next td */
    if(col_width[i] == $(this).outerWidth()) return 1;

    // the width to be set with substracted borders and paddings
    // (here we don't have margins)
    var new_width = col_width[i] - ($(this).outerWidth() - $(this).width());
    $(this).width(new_width);

    // I have also tried this, but the result was the same:
    // $(this).css('width', new_width + 'px');
});
```

I should notice that `thead th` and `tbody td` are from different tables (as I mentioned before)

### Another try

Another thing I tried - adding one pixel to each column - `$(this).width(new_width + 1);`. And on the demo page it worked. I copied the new code to the real page and on the almost all tables it worked! There was only one table where there was a problem.
It proved that the container (where the table was in), was not wide enough, so the scrollbar "made" the columns shorter. Of course, I expanded the container's width. The problem disappeared.

---

### The real question

And while asking (writing) this long question, I solved it! So now it is changing a little bit: **why**?

Why when I added one extra pixel, the problem disappeared? Why the `computed width` is different from the `real width`?

Of course, I will be happy if you provide me another, more professional solution :)

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rsjv4ttd/) (with already set widths, copied from the chrome console). Resize the `result` box to see the whole table properly.

Comment: can you share the HTML markup as well as the CSS that is generating this table issue? if it is too verbose, you can share a link to a JSfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

The difference in computed width and real width is due to the use of border-collapse: collapse.

border-collapse: collapse

> Borders are collapsed into a single border when possible (border-spacing and empty-cells properties will be ignored)

This reduces the width by 1px for each of the td elements, since each has had its border reduced to a single border.

Answer (score 0):

Computed width is different from real width because every element has 1px border and 1 px white space in left and right, same as top and bottom.

Comment: What is `white space`? Is it padding or what?

Comment: a simple space. I called white space but is a space 1px space.

Comment: that is why if you make 4 divs with 25% width in a wraper of 100% won't work. Because of that extra 1px border and 1px space at each side.

Comment: and its 99 px in your case because it merges the spaces or borders in one and.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm getting all white spaces using `($(this).outerWidth() - $(this).width());` so it should not be the problem, I think. The way you say this is like I cannot capture this `white space` using jQuery.

Comment: Just try to add 1 more px to your width to see what it happens. This is tricky. Please thumb up if you understood the answer.

Comment: also change overflow to hidden and put the data in the same table. don't make 2 tables because it will render different even if you specify the width.

Comment: If you didn't read my question, I tried adding 1 pixel and it worked. What I'm asking is why is this happening? Where can I read more about this 'white space'? `'also change overflow to hidden and put the data in the same table'`. What do you mean? Can you edit my jsfiddle, please?